# How can I change data scheme in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a data like below;

```
{
  "house": {
    "subname1": {
      "active": true,
      "address": "123 street"
    },
    "subname2": {
      "active": true,
      "address": "123 street"
    }
  },
  "business": {
    "example": {
      "active": true,
      "address": "123 street"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to change to this;

```
{"type" : "house", "subtype" : "subname1", "active" : true, "address" : "123 street"},
{"type" : "house", "subtype" : "subname2", "active" : true, "address" : "123 street"},
{"type" : "business", "subtype" : "example", "active" : true, "address" : "123 street"}
```

I used Lodash. I am not sure this is right way. 
and don't know how to add

```
    _.map(formData, (r,v,k) => {
      _.map(r, (re,key,ke) => {
        _.map(re, (a,b,c) => {

        newObj["type"] = v;
        newObj["name"] = key;
        //need to be added c object more
        })
      })
    })
```

below is what I achieve until now.

```
{
  name: "example",
  type: "business"
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried specifically?

Comment: Please include an attempt you tried as a [mcve]. Show some effort!

Comment: I will update my effort soon

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

```js
var obj = {"house":{"subname1":{"active":true,"address":"123 street"},"subname2":{"active":true,"address":"123 street"}},"business":{"example":{"active":true,"address":"123 street"}}};

var result = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((type) => {
  Object.keys(obj[type]).forEach((subtype) => {
    result.push({
        type : type,
        subtype : subtype,
        ...obj[type][subtype]
    });
  });  
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! you saved me :)

Comment: @Victoria - Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to give your object a parent key called `type`.

If so, try it this way:

```js
var type = {
  "house": {
    "subname1": {
      "active": true,
      "address": "123 street"
    },
    "subname2": {
      "active": true,
      "address": "123 street"
    }
  },
  "business": {
    "example": {
      "active": true,
      "address": "123 street"
    }
  }
}

var object = object || {};
object.type = type;
console.log(object);
```